# Records for last 30 days, only getting one record per day rather than all records per day

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do:

Modify a sql query to give slightly more specific data.

Brief Data summary: I'm pulling a report on Call center representatives. This shows call data like duration of call, if it was inbound/outbound, missed call, etc. The idea is to get a report for the last 30 days showing every call the CSR took for each day. For example, if extension 7200 took 5 calls per day, in the last 30 days the report should show 150 calls just for that rep.

However what it is currently doing is pulling only one call per rep per day. So with 15 reps, I'm getting only 15 rows per date and so my report is only around 345 rows currently.

Here is the query:

```
Insert into test.AMBrawDataDump(
            Extension, 
            Start_Time,
            End_Time,
            Duration, 
            Inbound_Answered, 
            Missed, 
            Outbound, 
            Hold_Time,
            Call_term_reason)  
SELECT 
              c.extension -- USER EXTENSION
            , b.STARTTIME -- Start of call
            , b.ENDTIME   -- End of call
            , b.DURATION  -- Length of call
            , CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Inbound_Answered  -- Inbound answered 
calls
            , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 0
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Missed             -- Missed Calls
            , CASE WHEN a.LEGTYPE1 = 1
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Outbound               -- Outbound calls
            , a.HOLDTIMESECS -- Hold time in seconds
            , a. TERMINATIONREASONCODE
FROM cdrdb.session a
INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
 ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
 ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
 WHERE b.ts BETWEEN curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
 AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
 group by DATE(b.ts),c.extension;
```

So the data being pulled is correct (this was done by grouping by Date(b.ts) and c.extension), however, it's only pulling one call per rep per day, instead of all calls per rep per day.

Is there an obvious thing I should be doing here to get this data?

Comment: may be because of GROUP BY

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: So if I definitely need every call for each day in the 30 day interval but I also need each extension per call (for record and metric purposes) how would I change that group by?

Comment: @jarlh to clarify, if I group only by extension, i get 15 records: One random call per agent. If i group by Date(b.ts) then I get 30 records, which is random calls for the last 30 days. But I need every call the each agent took for the past 30 days

Comment: The question is: Why do you even group if you want to have every single call?
Just remove the ` group by DATE(b.ts),c.extension`

Comment: Wow @JanZeiseweis thank you, not sure why I didn't try that. I though I had to at least group by extension